# Expressão regular para numero, virgulas e pontos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando pegar um conteúdo especifico de uma string que é retornada no javascript.

Pensei em pegar o match dele com expressão regular para pegar exatamente os numeros, pontos e virgulas do retorno monetário que tem em parte do texto, o problema está que as letras também vem no retorno.

Por exemplo, tenho a frase "Total Estimado Vigente: R$ 209.502,84"

Queria pegar só o 209.502,84

Cheguei até então em

```
var total = $(".totalEstimadoVigente").html().match("(?:\.|,|[0-9])*").join('');
```

Como solucionar essa ER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente a seguinte expressão: `[\d\.\,]+`

No seu código:

```
var total = $(".totalEstimadoVigente").html().match(/[\d\.\,]+/g).join('');
```

O valor de retorno com a String `Total Estimado Vigente: R$ 209.502,84` será:

```
209.502,84
```

Comment: Em Expressões Regulares não se utiliza aspas para definição. É necessário colocar `/` no começo e fim.

Comment: Beleza, perfeitamente mano, está perfeito

Comment: Não seria mais fácil usar `+` ao invés de `{1,}` ?

Comment: @Isac para a escrita e leitura sim, mas dá na mesma. É que conforme fui efetuando os testes esqueci deste detalhe.